# Switch to open Explorer window that is already at the desired folder instead of opening a second window

Tags: vb.net-2010

My vb.net application creates files and then opens Explorer at the folder holding the newly created files. It uses Process.Start to do this. The result is a new Explorer window every time. I would like the application to recycle any Explorer window that is already open at the target folder instead of starting a new window. If it does this then it should leave any other open Explorer windows alone. I am thinking to do this the application must check all current Explorer processes for their current locations and then switch to the one that might be applicable instead of starting a new process. Help towards how can I accomplish the desired affect would be much appreciated. Thank you.